# Regex expression for checking if a string contains a valid script tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex expression that tests whether a given string has a valid script tag. If for example a page contains within it

```
<body>Body goes here</body>
<script src = "page.js"></script>
```

Testing this string (the HTML source of the page in this case) with the regex test method should return true since there is a valid script tag. Similarly a URL with a valid script tag like:

```
https://url.com/something.php?getp=<script>func();</script>
```

should also return true. However, something like:

```
https://url.com/something.php?getp=<script</script>
```

should return false since it is not a valid script tag.

Any advice on how to go about this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a "valid script tag" is in the context of a generic string?

Answer (score 4):

Use `DOMParser` to turn the string into a document, and then with `querySelector`, check to see if the document has any `script` tags:

```js
const hasScript = str => Boolean(
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').querySelector('script')
);

console.log(hasScript('https://url.com/something.php?getp=<script<\/script>'));
console.log(hasScript('https://url.com/something.php?getp=<script><\/script>'));
console.log(hasScript(`<body>Body goes here</body>
<script src = "page.js"><\/script>`));
console.log(hasScript('https://url.com/something.php?getp=<script>func();<\/script>'));
```

DOMParser *is* safe - the content of the script tags won't be executed during parsing.

Comment: 100% was going to write the same thing. Using regular expressions to parse markup is too error-prone, it's likely best to let the browser handle the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
/(<script\s*>\w.+<\/script\s*>)|(<script\s*src\s*=\s*"[A-Za-z0-9]+\.js"\s*><\/script\s*>)/g
```

Try this in [regexr](https://regexr.com/4lpni)